# Undefined variable error in view even after passing the data from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a simple calculator that will perform calculation by unitary method

Below is my controller

class Calculator extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();


    $this->load->helper('url');
}

    public function index()
    {
        $mid_cal = 0;
        $total_cost = 0;
        $this->load->view('Calculator',$total_cost,$mid_cal);
        //print_r($total_cost);

    }

    public function calculate()
    {
        //print_r($_POST);
        $qty_purchased = $this->input->post('qty_purchased');
        $item_cost = $this->input->post('item_cost');
        $mid_cal = $item_cost / $qty_purchased;
        $qty_used = $this->input->post('qty_used');
        $total_cost = $mid_cal * $qty_used ; 
        $this->load->view('Calculator',$total_cost,$mid_cal); 

        //$this->load->view('calculator');
    }


}
```

Below is my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/calculator/calculate" method='post'>
  Item:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item" >
  <br>
  Qty Purchased:<br>
  <input type="text" name="qty_purchased" >
  <br>
  Cost of Item:<br>
  <input type="text" name="item_cost" >
  <br>
  Mid Cal:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mid_cal" value="<?php echo $mid_cal ?>">
  <br>
  Qty Used:<br>
  <input type="text" name="qty_used" >
  <br>
  Total Cost:<br>
  <input type="text" name="total_cost" value="<?php echo $total_cost ?>">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 



</body>
</html>
```

I am getting undefined variable error in view for $total_cost and $mid_cal. I am sending the data in the calculate function. I also tried sending blank data in my index function. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Any help will be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller.

Replace Index Method/Function with below and try.

```
public function index()
{
    $data['mid_cal'] = 0;
    $data['total_cost'] = 0;
    $this->load->view('calculator',$data);
    //print_r($total_cost);

}
```

You have to pass an array in controller to the view as like above and now you can access directly using $total_cost and $mid_cal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my issue. Just one more thing how can I use the set value function in the view form. I want all my data to stay even when the page is loaded to calculate() function from index() function. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Solved that problem also.